# Does index range scan cause 'Using index condition'?

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

When only cluster key and `idx_price` exist as indexes..

Query: `select id , name from product where price < 20000`

Explane:

| detail | value |
| --- | --- |
| id | 1 |
| select_type | SIMPLE |
| table | product |
| partitions | NULL |
| type | range |
| possible_keys | idx_price |
| key | idx_price |
| key_len | 9 |
| ref | NULL |
| rows | 7 |
| filtered | 100.00 |
| Extra | Using index condition |
| 1 row in set 1 warning (0.00 sec) |  |

As far as I know, the `Using index condition` occurs depending on the presence or absence of the index of `where clause`.

But I just created and used `idex_price` for where clause.

What did I miss?

Comment: If you don't have an index, it has to do a full scan to test the condition on every row. If you have an index, it uses the index. Isn't that what you expect?

Comment: This means it is using the index to satisfy your where clause, but still needs to access the row in the clustered index to read the other columns, as they are not contained in the index. If you add the `name` column to your index it would be "covering". See [`Using index`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information) and [`Using index condition`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information:~:text=Using%20index%20condition).

Comment: @Barmar I wonder why 'Using index condition' occurs in that query

Comment: @user1191247 'Extra : Using index condition' is same 'Index Condition Pushdown(ICP)' ?
If it means the same, why did 'ICP' occur in that query? Does index range scan cause 'ICP'?

Comment: @user1191247 As far as I know, 'ICP' can occur when columns that exist in 'where clause' do not exist in the index table. So why does ICP occur when only 'price' exists in the 'where clause' of that query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Extra: Using index condition" means that it's making use of [Index Condition Pushdown Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html). It's using the `idx_price` index to optimize the `price < 20000` condition in the `WHERE` clause. Instead of scanning the table data to find the rows that satisfy the condition, it only scans the index.

"Type: range" means that only rows in the range `< 20000` are retrieved. Since indexes are B-trees, range conditions are easily optimized. In this case it can search the B-tree for `20000` and then return all the rows before this in the tree.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the detail. I guess I lacked an understanding of the 'ICP',

Answer (score 0):

Before ICP (see Barmar's answer), the "Handler" took care of some of the filtering.  With the Pushdown, the storage engine (InnoDB) does more of work.  The performance benefit comes from not going back and forth between the Handler and the Storage Engine.

ICP, I think, only refers to the `WHERE` clause.

"Using index" is a better Extra -- It says that all the columns *anywhere* in the `SELECT` were found in the `INDEX`.  That is, the query can be completely performed using only the index's BTree -- no bouncing back and forth between that and the data's BTree.

Comment: Then, should I understand that the `price<2000` clause caused 'ICP'?

Comment: If so, I was expecting `using where`, but I posted this question because "ICP" occurred.

Comment: @tray - Without `name` (and with the range test on `price`), the entire query could be performed in the index ("Using index").  Without the range test, there would be a table scan -- likely to be much slower.